# Android WebView removes class from my HTML

Tags: android, html, css, webview, android-webview

I am using the webview to display the following HTML:

```
<p>
   <span class="clarity-word">
      <mark class="selected">When</mark>
   </span>
   <mark class="selected"> in the course</mark> of human events.
</p>
```

The first `<mark>` works and formats just fine, drawing in the .selected stylings. However, the second `<mark>` is stripped away from the webview whenever I load it. This results in the following:

```
<p>
   <span class="clarity-word">
      <mark class="selected">When</mark>
   </span>
   <mark class> in the course</mark> of human events.
</p>
```

The second `<mark>`'s class is being stripped away upon being rendered by the webview. I need it to stay there.

Comment: You posted the same source twice.

Comment: look closely, line 5 is different...hence...the reason for asking the question

Comment: How do you know that something is stripped away? How do you manage to look in the source?

Comment: Using chrome://inspect